# querySelector working in devtools console but not in Selenium 'execute_script' with CSS selector

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver

When I load the page on Chrome without Selenium, and run the same querySelector function the console, the correct element is returned, however when using driver.execute_script with the same querySelector function None is returned.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options as ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.bestbuy.com/site/searchpage.jsp?st=4090&_dyncharset=UTF-8&_dynSessConf=&id=pcat17071&type=page&sc=Global&cp=1&nrp=&sp=&qp=&list=n&af=true&iht=y&usc=All+Categories&ks=960&keys=keys'

selector = 'div#pricing-price-60753325 > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > span'

driver.get(url)

WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, "html")))

sleep(5)

elem = driver.execute_script(f'document.querySelector("{selector}")')

print(elem)

driver.quit()
```

You can even try it on the devtools console and see that `document.querySelector('div#pricing-price-60753325 > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > span')` returns `<span aria-hidden="true">$1,699.99</span>` as it should. I have also tried using xpath with execute_script and query selector, and driver.findElement() by xpath and css selector to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `return` inside your execute_script as shown below.

it is important to use `return` in your query, if you are fetching some data.

```
elem = driver.execute_script(f'return document.querySelector("{selector}");')
```

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention I tried that too, unfortunately.

Comment: You can try adding **.textContent** in your query, It may work for you 
`driver.execute_script(f'return document.querySelector("{selector}").textContent;')`